# Could not find or load main class com.simplilearn.testing.oops.LunchNewBrowser Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException error using Selenium Java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, firefox, geckodriver

please i really need help on this..i haven't been able to progress since yesterday. please can anyone help me out. for some reasons i haven't been able to lunch my browser below is my script and error message

```
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class LaunchBrowser {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "/Users/spectra/eclipse-workspace/Drivers/geckodriver");
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(40,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(90, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.get("https://www.google.com");
    }
}
```

---

Error:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class com.simplilearn.testing.oops.LunchNewBrowser
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.simplilearn.testing.oops.LunchNewBrowser
```

Comment: Please read: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

Answer (score 0):

This error message...

```
Error: Could not find or load main class com.simplilearn.testing.oops.LunchNewBrowser
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.simplilearn.testing.oops.LunchNewBrowser
```

...implies that the *main class* was not found by the *JVM*.

The complete error stack trace would have been of some help to debug the issue in a better way. However, I don't see any error in your code block. But it seems there's is an issue loading the *main class*.

---

### Solution

Create a new *Java* project and write the program afresh adding the required jar files and importing the required classes. You should be good to go.

---

### Additional Considerations

Ensure that:

- *JDK* is upgraded to  current levels [JDK 8u252](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html).
- *Selenium* is upgraded to  current released [Version 3.141.59](https://www.selenium.dev/downloads/).
- *ChromeDriver* is updated to  current [ChromeDriver v84.0](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=84.0.4147.30/) level.
- *Chrome* is updated to  current *Chrome Version 84.0* level. (as per [ChromeDriver v84.0 release notes](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/84.0.4147.30/notes.txt))
- If your base *Web Client* version is too old, then uninstall it and install a recent GA and released version of *Web Client*.
- *Clean* your *Project Workspace* through your *IDE* and *Rebuild* your project with required dependencies only.
- (*WindowsOS only*) Use [*CCleaner*](https://www.ccleaner.com/ccleaner) tool to wipe off all the OS chores before and after the execution of your *Test Suite*.
- (*LinuxOS only*) [Free Up and Release the Unused/Cached Memory in Ubuntu/Linux Mint](http://www.yourownlinux.com/2013/10/how-to-free-up-release-unused-cached-memory-in-linux.html) before and after the execution of your *Test Suite*.
- Take a *System Reboot*.
- Execute your `@Test` as **non-root** user.
- Always invoke `driver.quit()` within `tearDown(){}` method to close & destroy the *WebDriver* and *Web Client* instances gracefully.